# How to run pySpark code on multiple workers in AWS glue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Glue Table. The table has been created by crawling an S3 bucket that contains parquet files. The data is partitioned by year/month/day.

I fetch the Dynamic Frame of a specific partition first. That’s easy.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "testdata", table_name = "sampletable", transformation_ctx = "datasource0",push_down_predicate = "(year == '2019' and month == '08' and day == '02')")
```

I want to find the max value of a specific column. That’s straightforward as well:

```
max = datasource0.toDF().agg({“my-col”:”max”}).first()[0]
```

When I launched this job, I selected 10 workers (the default).

- Is the `create_dynamic_frame` being processed on 10 worker?
- Is the `agg` function being processed on 10 workers?

If the answer is yes, how can I get this intuition? If the answer is no, then, how can I make it so?

My objective is to speed up the execution of the above code, which runs today in 5 min.

Comment: enable metrics and try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-debug-capacity.html

Answer (score 0):

I think when working with dataframes, the glue spark cluster will handle the parallelization.

You can get a count of partitions using:

```
datasource0.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

If you are working with custom functions (UDFs), you can in the distributed functions get a handle to the execution context:

```
ctx = TaskContext()
logger.warning(f"PartitionID: {ctx.partitionId()}")
```